# Convert varchar to datetime in sql which is having millisec

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column `abc varchar(100)` with data like `2011-09-26 16:36:57.810000`

I want to convert this column to `DATETIME`...

But doing a

```
Convert(DATETIME, abc,120)
```

is giving this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can any one please help me convert my `varchar` format to `datetime` in SQL Server 2008?

Thanks in advance

Comment: String `2011-09-26 16:36:57.810000` can't be converted to datetime. Milliseconds can have only 0-999.

Comment: But how can i convert this column to a DATETIME then any other ways

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use style 121 but you can have **only 3 digits for milliseconds** (i.e `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)`) format.

```
declare @abc varchar(100)='2011-09-26 16:36:57.810' 
select convert(datetime,@abc,121)
```

So you can sort it out by limiting the varchar field to 23 characters before converting as:

```
declare @abc varchar(100)='2011-09-26 16:36:57.810000' 
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(23),@abc),121)
```

Or use the `Left()` function to get first 23 characters as:

```
select convert(datetime,left(@abc,23),121)
```

Try to avoid storing date as string.

Comment: I already have Users data given in 6 digit mellisec.., so i think i need to split last 3 digits?

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure milliseconds has only 3 digits before converting. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You should also be wary of the precision of the DateTime type - for example .997 will be retained correctly, but casting a value like .998 or .999 will result in the value being rounded to the closest second.

Answer (score 5):

In case you need 6 digits precision use `DATETIME2`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2016-08-09T08:08:50.358000', 126) as MSSQLDateTime2
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-08-09T08:08:50.358', 126) as MSSQLDateTime
```

Comment: Ops, sorry. Datetime2 is available form SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server only supports 3 decimal places for milliseconds, so the following will work:

```
Convert(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(abc, 0, 24) ,120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on GBrian's answer, I came up with:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME2, abc, 126))
```

I haven't benchmarked how this stacks up against the substring-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the following string variables:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(100)  = '2020-04-06T04:35:07.9490051Z' -- 7 digits nanoseconds
DECLARE @d1 VARCHAR(100) = '2020-04-05T15:00:00Z'         -- simple: without nanoseconds
```

I came up to the solution using [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@d,19) + 'Z' AS DATETIME)  -- outputs: 2020-04-06 04:35:07.000
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@d1,19) + 'Z' AS DATETIME) -- outputs: 2020-04-05 15:00:00.000
```