# Handling millisecond in SQL with IsDate() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I need to cast the above DATE column of varchar to date format. So I used,

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Tagname]
  ,FORMAT((CASE WHEN 1 = ISDATE(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR))THEN CAST(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR)AS datetime) else NULL END ), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff' ) AS [Date]
  ,[Value]
  ,[VValue]
  ,[OPCQuality]
  ,[QualityDetail]
  ,[QualityDescription]
  ,[StatusCode]
  ,[ErrorMessage] FROM [Dashboard].[dbo].[Data20170202123655985]
```

while using this, the fields with milliseconds that has more than 3 digit are not converted to date. And my resultant table is,

[image]

Comment: What server are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL,....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert varchar to datetime in sql which is having millisec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025192/convert-varchar-to-datetime-in-sql-which-is-having-millisec)

Comment: @pringi, looks like SQL Server from the looks of his syntax

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax used

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` does not have sufficient precision to accurately handle milliseconds. Try instead converting your varchar data to [DateTime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx).

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Tagname]
  ,FORMAT((CASE WHEN 1 = ISDATE(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR))THEN CAST(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR)AS datetime2) else NULL END ), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff' ) AS [Date]
  ,[Value]
  ,[VValue]
  ,[OPCQuality]
  ,[QualityDetail]
  ,[QualityDescription]
  ,[StatusCode]
  ,[ErrorMessage] FROM [Dashboard].[dbo].[Data20170202123655985]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select     FORMAT((CASE WHEN  TRY_CONVERT(datetime2,CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR)) IS NOT NULL THEN 
                       CAST(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR)AS datetime2) 
                  else 
                       null 
                   END ), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff' ) AS [Date]
```

see these two tests, I think the problem is in isdate as well as datetime2 possibly

declare @date as nvarchar(50) = '2016-03-10T09:53:39.138222Z';

```
--still didn't seem to work
select FORMAT((CASE WHEN 1 = ISDATE(CAST(@date AS VARCHAR))THEN 
      CAST(CAST(@date AS VARCHAR)AS datetime2) 
   else 
      NULL 
   END ), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff' ) AS [Date]

--does now work
 select     FORMAT((CASE WHEN  TRY_CONVERT(datetime2,CAST(@Date AS VARCHAR)) IS NOT NULL THEN 
      CAST(CAST(@Date AS VARCHAR)AS datetime2) 
 else 
      null 
 END ), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff' ) AS [Date]
```